# Exchanging content in two files

Tags: python

I am working on this problem and having trouble coming up with code for it:

Write a program that prompts for two file names and exchanges the contents of the two files. Your program should be sufficiently robust that if a file doesn’t exist, the program will reprompt.

This is all I have so far:

```
File1 = input(“Input file 1 name:”)
File2 = input(“Input file 2 name:”)

File1 = “file1.txt”, w+
File2 = “file2.txt”, w+
```

Any tips would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Answer (score 3):

One way could be to consider swapping the file names:

```
import os

File1 = input("Input file 1 name:")
File2 = input("Input file 2 name:")

os.rename(File2, 'temp')
os.rename(File1, File2)
os.rename('temp', File1)
```

Comment: You'd want to follow that up with shutil.copystat to get all the permissions bits swapped between the two.

Answer (score 0):

This simple code can be used to swap content between two txt files

```
File1 = input("Input file 1 name:") # Path for 1st File
File2 = input("Input file 2 name:") # Path for 2nd File

Que = open(File1,'r+')
Ans = open(File2,'r+')

content_que = Que.readlines()
content_ans = Ans.readlines()


Que.seek(0) 
Que.truncate() 


Ans.seek(0) 
Ans.truncate() 

Que.writelines(content_ans)
Ans.writelines(content_que)
Que.close()
Ans.close()
```

Comment: If you're not doing anything with the lines of the files, just using `read()` and `write()` is probably better than using `readlines()` and `writelines()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using python, here's my code :

---

```
    # Start
    with open('abc.txt', 'r+') as file1:
      file1_r = file1.read()
      with open('def.txt', 'r+') as file2:
        file2_r = file2.read()
        print(f'Before exchanging the contents - \n{file1_r} \n\n{file2_r} \n')

        # Place the Cursor to the Beginning of Files
        file1.seek(0), file2.seek(0)

        # Writing contents of one to another
        file1.write(file2_r), file2.write(file1_r)

        # Probabaly there are leftover contents of old file, that's why 
        # Remove the rest
        file1.truncate(), file2.truncate()
```

---